# Search text in different static html, stored in a variable using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, variables, search, static

I have fetched the html contents of multiple static pages using the following code, where **html_files** is an array of name of html files and **post_html** is a single file:

```
jQuery.each(html_files, function(index,post_html){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:post_html, //or the url to fetch data
        datatype:'html',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            // Search here.
         }
    });
});
```

Now i want to search for a text, entered in a text box, in each of this files, in the **data** variable.

How do i use contains() or content() to perform this. I want to perform the search in the client side only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What structure is inside `data` var?

Comment: it has static HTML files. @Justinas

Comment: maybe try loading the html into an `display: none` div and then parsing it. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is HTML structure, load it to virtual element, later do anything you want.

```
success: function (data) {
    var dom = $('<div>');
    dom.html(data);

    dom.find('.text-box').each(function () {
        enteredTextList.push($(this).val());
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to search a text entered in the text box. for eg:

        `var search = jQuery('#search-term').val();`

now i need to find **search** and wrap it in span tag as 
        `<span class="search-found">search</span>`

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution:

```
jQuery(data).find('p:contains("'+search+'")').each(function(){
    // Do sth
});
```